# How to associate a Jupyter Workspace Custom Container with it's Vertex AI Workbench instance

Tags: docker, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, google-cloud-vertex-ai, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I have multiple User Managed Vertex AI Workbench instances running in my GCP Project.
Each can run one or more Jupyter Workspaces by clicking `OPEN JUPYTERLAB`. Each Jupyter lab opens in a new browser tab.
From one of the Jupyter lab tabs, how can I tell which workbench instance or VM is hosting it?

EDIT: The first answer by  @[kiran mathew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17258510/kiran-mathew) is not working for me because I have a custom docker container and that solution returns the hostname of the container which is not set to the Workench instance name. I changed the title of the question to be specific to custom containers.

Comment: You can find your current instance with the following python code `import socket
instance_name = socket.gethostname() print(instance_name)`. Let me know if this helps or not.

Comment: The hostname is printing the hostname of a docker container, It prints 59afcc338ce2 which doesn't associate to the notebook.

Comment: I have provided an answer of what I am doing and what output I am getting. If this does not fulfill your requirements then can you provide more insights to your issue.

Comment: You can find the instance name by any of the following  curl commands
`!curl "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/name" -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"`   , `!curl "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/hostname" -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"` .Let me know if this helps you or not.

Comment: in upcoming versions end of Q1 we will offer a JupyterLab UI where you can see this information.

Comment: in the new upcoming version we will provide instance name in UI/JL DL container

Answer (score 0):

**Python code:**

```
import socket 
instance_name = socket.gethostname() 
print(instance_name)
```

I have two notebooks `stacckkk` and `stackoverflow2` . When I ran the above code in these two notebook individually I got the below results.

[image]

**Result:**

1st Notebook

[image]

2nd Notebook

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that. I need to modify my question to cover notebooks in docker containers.

Answer (score 0):

Using the URL solution in the comment by @KiranMathew, here is a function to return the workbook name that works with custom docker containers.

```py
    def get_workbook_name():
        url = "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/name"
        req = urllib.request.Request(url)
        req.add_header("Metadata-Flavor", "Google")
        workbook_name = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read().decode()
        return workbook_name
```

Still anticipating a simpler approach will be available as foreshadowed by @gogasca

You can also get the project id with: http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/project/project-id